Trouble with routes in CloudWays
I'm having some problems with NodeJS routes on the CloudWays application,
I have this example code, and only the root route works '/', all others get a status of 404 - how is this possible?
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const app = express();
app.use(cors()); // Habilitar CORS

// Defina seu token de acesso e store ID diretamente no código
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/teste', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello, your Node.js app is running on Cloudways!</h1>');
});


app.get("/produtos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.tiendanube.com/v1/${storeId}/products`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authentication: `bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "User-Agent": "Loja (example@email.com)",
        },
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Erro: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

const draftOrderData = {
  contact_name: "João",
  contact_lastname: "Paulo",
  contact_email: "example@gmail.com",
  payment_status: "unpaid",
  products: [
    {
      variant_id: 1048977915, // Substitua pelo ID do produto variante
      quantity: 1, // Propriedades customizadas, se necessário
    },
  ],
};
app.get("/carrinho", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.tiendanube.com/v1/${storeId}/draft_orders`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authentication: `bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "User-Agent": "Loja (exemple@email.com)",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(draftOrderData),
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Erro: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  } finally {
    return;
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta ${PORT}`);
});

Just need that all routes work at the same file, so I do not need to create one code of Node for each route I have just to put it at the root route.

Your server is not define / route, so only the root route works '/' seems weird. You may access the wrong server.

When I run your code, I get responses from /teste, /produtos and /carrinho.
For the first one I get your Hello message.
For the other two, I get back the JSON {"message":"storeId is not defined"} or {"message":"Erro: Unauthorized"} depending on what values I use for storeId and accessToken.
For completeness, when I try to access / I get the error "Cannot GET /"
